# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Number looking like that P-01-2.8-M in the database(DB) and I am using this query:

```
SELECT LEFT(No, CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) - 1) as Prefix 
FROM DB, Table 
WHERE No = GRNNo 
AND QtyLeft > 0 
AND No LIKE @No + '%' 
GROUP BY LEFT(No, CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) - 1) 
ORDER BY MAX(No)
```

I get the "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING funcion". Could you tell me where is the problem and if possible how to fix it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `LEFT(No, CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) - 1)` what are you trying to achieve with this? look for the second '-' then get rest of the string thereafter??

Comment: Why was this tagged vb.net? I've added sql-server tag based on syntax and error message.

Comment: @DannyJames get the string between the first "-" and the second "-" .

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tagged it as VB.net by habit, I usually post questions related to VB.net. Sorry about that

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of the values in your `no` column does not contain two hyphens. 
Change your query to

```
SELECT LEFT(No, CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) - 1) as Prefix 
FROM DB
INNER JOIN Table ON No = GRNNo 
WHERE QtyLeft > 0 
AND No LIKE @No + '%' 

AND CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) > 0

GROUP BY LEFT(No, CHARINDEX('-', No, CHARINDEX('-', No) + 1) - 1) 
ORDER BY MAX(No)
```

Please note I've also changed your implicit join to explicit join.